# Delete record in database if checkbox is unchecked

Tags: php, laravel

I have a checkbox field in my form, I want to insert data to database if the checkbox is checked and delete the data in database if the checkbox is unchecked.

Here is my checkbox code:

```
<ul class="list-unstyled mb-0">
   @foreach ($companies as $company)
   <li class="d-inline-block mr-2 mb-1">
      <fieldset>
         <div class="checkbox">
            <input type="checkbox" name="company_id[]"
            class="checkbox-input" value="{{ $company->id }}"
            id="{{ $company->id }}" 
            @foreach ($supervisor_company as $spv)
              @if ($spv != null)
                @if ($spv->company_id == $company->id)
                  checked
                @endif
              @endif
            @endforeach>
            <label for="{{ $company->id }}">{{ $company->name }}</label>
         </div>
      </fieldset>
   </li>
   <li class="d-inline-block mr-2 mb-1">
      @endforeach
</ul>
```

And this is my controller:

```
if ($request->has('company_id')) {
    foreach ($request->company_id as $key => $company) {
        $spv_data = EmployeeSpvCompany::where('employee_id', $employee_id)->where('company_id', $company)->first();
        if ($spv_data != null) {
            EmployeeSpvCompany::where('employee_id', $employee_id)->where('company_id', $company)->update(['company_id' => $company]);
        } else {
            $emp_spv = new EmployeeSpvCompany;
            $emp_spv->employee_id = $employee_id;
            $emp_spv->company_id = $company;
            $emp_spv->save();
        }
    }
}
```

Insert to database if the checkbox is checked is already working, but I don't know how to delete the data in database if the checkbox is unchecked

Comment: you would need to know the records you passed to the view to then compare to the list you get back ... also, in your controller it looks like you are attempting to recreate the `updateOrCreate` method (assuming you are only expecting to be updating 1 record) but you are not actually updating any field

Comment: @lagbox the update method in my code still not working. tbh, I'm trying to delete record not updating record. so...don't mind the update method

Comment: but in your code, you were trying to update the record instead of delete! or I miss something.

Comment: @SachinKumar Like I said, I don't have any idea how to do that. I'm just try anything that come to my head, so don't mind the update method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I expect the `company_id` field is a multi-select type so the value will be returned in the form of an array. I guess the following code will work in this situation.

```
$companyIds = $request->has('company_id'); // [1, 2]

if ($companyIds) {
    foreach ($companyIds as $company_id) {
        $employeeSpvCompanyInstance = EmployeeSpvCompany::firstOrCreate([
            'employee_id' => $employee_id,
            'company_id' => $company_id
        ]);
    }
    EmployeeSpvCompany::where('employee_id', $employee_id)->whereNotIn('company_id', $companyIds)->delete();
} else {
    EmployeeSpvCompany::where('employee_id', $employee_id)->delete();
}
```

Comment: This is more simple & specific than my code. I'm changing my `if` block to `firstOrCreate`. Thanks for your answer

Comment: Happy coding buddy!

Answer (score 1):

Ah!! I found something called `whereNotIn`. I just need to check if the data is not in my array request.

```
EmployeeSpvCompany::whereNotIn('company_id', $request->company_id)->delete();
```

Comment: I was writing my answer to my editor. But yes the same concept I wrote in my answer.